In Bazel, how to set the "parse_parallelism" flag in LcovMerger
I would like to set the "parse_parallelism" flag I found in the LcovMerger code here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator/LcovMergerFlags.java#L57)
How to set this flag from the bazel command? I tried passing in to bazel coverage (bazelisk coverage --combined_report=lcov --parse_parallelism=1) but it gets rejected by the CLI.
